# Look & feel option missing

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Look and feel option missing from portlet menu, i have attached an image below. Not sure if something has changed in the portal-ext.properties

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had you done something with this??

```
## Portlet CSS Portlet
# Set this to true to enable the ability to modify portlet CSS at runtime
# via the Look and Feel icon. Disabling it can speed up performance.
portlet.css.enabled=false
```

If yes try toggling the same.